# How Vue.js slice data by each group and show 3 rows at top then the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

How Vue.js slice data by each group and show 3 rows at top then the other?
I have data about 10 thousand to show，
I want group it and show 3 rows at top of each group by date then show the others left，
I don`t know how to do ，please help me,
thanks!

```
<div id="app">  
    <table class="table table-condensed">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>gender </th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="r in rows 
        | filterBy filter_name in 'name' 
        | recordLength 'filteredRowCount' 
        | limitBy countOfPage pageStart ">
        <td>{{ (currPage-1) * countOfPage + $index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.gender }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
  </div>
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows: [],
    countOfPage: 5,
    currPage: 1,
    filter_name: ''
  },
  computed: {
  filteredRows: function(){
    var filter_name = this.filter_name.toLowerCase();
    return ( this.filter_name.trim() !== '' ) ? 
      this.rows.filter(function(d){ return     d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter_name) > -1; }) : 
    this.rows;
  },
    pageStart: function(){
        return (this.currPage - 1) * this.countOfPage;
      },
    totalPage: function(){
      return Math.ceil(this.filteredRows.length / this.countOfPage);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setPage: function(idx){
      if( idx <= 0 || idx > this.totalPage ){
        return;
      }
      this.currPage = idx;
    },
  },
  created: function(){
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON("Json data", function(data) {
      self.rows = data;
    })
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the layout you've described, but you are asking about grouping by date so the following code may help.

It's plain javascript which I import into the Vue component to transform the data after fetch.

The input is an array of objects with a date property to be grouped on. The output is an array of object with two props - date key and a nested array of the grouped objects.

```js
export default {
  filesByDate(files) {
    return filesByDate(files);
  }
}

const filesByDate = (files) => {
  const keyFn = (file) => { return formatDate(file.effectiveDate); };
  return groupBy(files, keyFn)
    .map(group => { return { date: group.key, files: group.group }; });
}

const groupBy = (arr, keyFn) => {
  const grouped = arr.reduce( (grouping, item) => {
    const key = keyFn(item);
    grouping[key] = grouping[key] || [];
    grouping[key].push(item);
    return grouping;
  }, {} );
  return Object.keys(grouped)
    .map(key => { return {key: key, group: grouped[key]}; });
}

const formatDate = (date) => {
  let d = new Date(date);
  let month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
  let day = '' + d.getDate();
  let year = d.getFullYear();
  month = month.length < 2 ? '0' + month : month;
  day = day.length < 2 ? '0' + day : day;
  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```